# Determine whether infinite row converges

Tags: convergence-divergence, complex-numbers

I've been giving the infinite row:

$$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{nb+a}{n}$$

I am first suppose to check whether it converges for $b = 9$ and $a = 2$, and then I have to figure out for which numbers of a,b it converges. I tried all of the criterias I can think of to figure out whether it converges, but They don't really seem to tell anything.

Except for the criteria that says that if $a_n$ doesn't go towards zero for $n \to \infty$ then the row diverges. When i try to write: `limit(the expression,n=infinity)` in maple I get the result `-9-9i..9+9i` but I'm not quite sure how to interpret this, and whether it can tell me anything about the convergence

Comment: So, based on your message... Does your term $a_n$ go to zero? For what value(s) of $b$ will it go to zero? (this is a required condition for convergence -- not a sufficient one). And for values of $b$ for which the term does go to zero, then the $(-1)^n$ (alternating sign) should prompt you, as a first approach, to see if you can apply the [Alternating test for series.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test)

Comment: ooh yeah, I'll try to do that :)

Comment: Note also, with regard to your Maple result, that "the term does not converge to zero" does not mean "the term has a limit different than zero." In your case, $(-1)^n \frac{9n+2}{n}$ may not have a limit at all...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we consider
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n} \left(\frac{nb+a}{n} \right)
$$
Re-writing the fraction and expanding the sum gives us
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n} \left(b +\frac{a}{n} \right)= -(b+a)+\left(b+\frac{a}{2}\right)-\left(b+\frac{a}{3}\right)+\ldots
$$
Now,
$$
-(b+a)+\left(b+\frac{a}{2}\right)-\left(b+\frac{a}{3}\right)+\ldots
$$
$$
=-b-a+b+\frac{a}{2}-b-\frac{a}{3}+\ldots
$$
$$
=(-b+b-b+\ldots)+\left(-a+\frac{a}{2}-\frac{a}{3}+\ldots\right)
$$
$$
=\left(-a+\frac{a}{2}-\frac{a}{3}+\ldots\right)
$$
Factoring $-a$ we have
$$
=-a \left(1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}-\ldots\right)
$$
But since 
$$
\left(1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}+\ldots\right) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\left(-1\right)^{n+1}}{n} = \log{2}
$$
We have
$$
-a \left(1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}-\ldots\right) = -a \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\left(-1\right)^{n+1}}{n} = -a\log{2}
$$
Now, though the Sum converges for any $a$ and $b = 0$, the Sum does not converge for $b \neq 0$ as a consequence of the [nth-term test for divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_test).

Comment: I'm not quite sure I get this - wouldn't this mean that it converges for any a or b?

Comment: Actually it does, just not to the same value.

Comment: Okay - it is just that know I tried to look at it as an alternating series with $b_n = b +\frac{a}{n}$. And then the way i get it, is that Leibniz says that it only will converge if $b_n$ -> 0 for n -> infinity. And i would just mean that it wouldn't go to zero if b is anything other than 0 ?

Comment: Yes, but notice that if $b_{n}=b+\frac{a}{n}$ , as $n \to \infty$ $b_{n} \to b$, which is why although Leibniz's statement is true, it does not apply to the Sum you wrote.

Comment: @zickens -- but the series does **not** converge for $b \neq 0$. Not with the standard definition of convergence.

Comment: How so? @ClementC. Could you write as to why it doesn't?

Comment: [Because the general term of the sum does not converge to zero.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_tests#Limit_of_the_summand)

Comment: Through Leibniz Criteria? As far as my understanding goes, the Leibniz Criteria is not exclusive in that way.

Comment: This is a theorem about convergence. Leibniz's criterion has nothing to do with it; and yes, actually (and of course) [it does](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeibnizCriterion.html). You cannot have a theorem showing that a non-converging series converges; so Leibniz's criterion (a.k.a. alternating series test) has as hypothesis that $a_n\to 0$.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! I'll extend my answer right away.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Note that $$(-1)^n\frac{nb+a}n=(-1)^n\left(b+\frac a n\right).$$ From this, you should be able to determine a necessary condition for convergence, using reasoning you've already mentioned. Once you've determined that, you should readily be able to show that it is sufficient, too.